# Why Serialize() returning incorrect values?

Tags: javascript

I used serialize() for my form post, but I am getting strange values, for instance,

`fone=%E5%92%B8%E5%91%B3%E8%BE%83%E9%87%8D`.

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks
Li

Comment: `serialize()` doesn't do that, it looks like you also called `urlencode()`.

Comment: Form data is supposed to be URL-encoded. But the receiver should automatically decode this, so you should never see it.

Comment: you can decode it: `decodeURIComponent("fone=%E5%92%B8%E5%91%B3%E8%BE%83%E9%87%8D");`
`=> "fone=咸味较重"`

Comment: Thank both of you. I will decode it now.